# dnsruby gem: Get parsed version of dnsruby output

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't find anything in the official documentation of the dnsruby gem, so I'll ask here: Is there any chance to get a parsed version of the dnsruby outputs, especially for A-Record?

When I'm performing:

`def find_domain
    self.domain_name = Reversed.lookup(self.ip_address)
    res = Resolver.new
    a_recs = res.query(self.domain_name) # Defaults to A record
  end`

the output of a_recs is a long string, e.g.:

> ;; Answer received from 192.168.178.1 (75 bytes) ;; ;; Security Level : UNCHECKED ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59802 ;; flags: qr rd ra cd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1 OPT pseudo-record : payloadsize 512, xrcode 0, version 0, flags 32768 ;; QUESTION SECTION (1 record) ;; google-public-dns-b.google.com. IN    A ;; ANSWER SECTION (1 record) google-public-dns-b.google.com.  86399   IN  A   8.8.4.4

I just need the IP-Address (in this case: 8.8.4.4) itself and not the whole answer to my query. Is there a solution? I want to avoid doing that the "dirty" way.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without having done any research into this gem, my inclination would be to regex match an IPV4 address from the response.  Have you tried the demo progs it ships with?  https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seperating the whole string into single words with `.split` and save the values into an array. Then I'm going to loop through them and pick the last value. Something like this (note tested):

```
a_recs = res.query(self.domain_name).split

a_recs.each do |ip|
 a_recs = ip
end
```

When iterating through the array the last values are getting overwritten so the last one (in my case the IP-address 8.8.4.4) should be saved to `a_recs`.